# Getting fields on Pivot table through laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a Pivot table M:N relationship in Laravel 5.5.

Essentially my datastructure is;

```
Table_A
---------
id
name


Table_A_has_table_B <pivot>
---------
table_a_id
table_b_id
other_field


Table_B
---------
id
name
```

In my `Table_A` Model I have

```
public function tableb()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Table_B', 'Table_A_has_table_B', 'table_a_id', 'table_b_id');
}
```

And finally in my blade views I have this

```
        @foreach ($tablea->tableb as $tbl)
          <p><a href="#">{{ $tbl->name }}</a></p>
          <p>{{ $tbl->other_field}}</p>
        @endforeach
```

All which seems to be working except the final line

`{{ $tbl->other_field}}`

How do I access the field on the pivot table and the data on `tableb`.
The pivot table contains information pertinent to the current view related to `tableb`.

**Schema**

```
    Schema::create('Table_A_has_table_B', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('table_a_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('table_b_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('other_field')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(['table_a_id', 'competitor_id']);
        $table->foreign('table_a_id')->references('id')->on('table_a')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('table_b_id')->references('id')->on('table_b')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `->withPivot('column1', 'column2');` in your relationship like this ([Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)):

```
public function tableb()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Table_B', 'Table_A_has_table_B', 'table_a_id', 'table_b_id')->withPivot('other_field');
}
```

Then use the `pivot` key word like this :

```
{{ $tbl->pivot->other_field}}
```

Comment: Thanks Maraboc, I did try this as it was in the docs but it did not work.

Comment: I just added my schema for the Pivot table.

Comment: Happy to help :)